# JQuery not working with Jade

Tags: javascript, jquery, pug

I have some JQuery inside my Jade files for my Express web app, but nothing seems to be getting called. Here's the content jade file:

```
extends layout
block content
    p Landing page
    #info Info area
block foot
    a(href="https://localhost:8888/logout", title="logout") Logout
```

Here's the layout jade file:

```
!!!5
html
    head
        title #{title}
        link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/style.css')
        script(type='text/javascript', src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js")
        script(type='text/javascript', src="/idle-timer.js")
        script(type='text/javascript').
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $(document).idleTimer(10000);
                $(document).on("idle.idleTimer", function(){
                    console.log("alert");
                });

                $(#info).click(function(){
                    $(this).hide();
                });
            });
    body
        header
            h1 Web App Sample
        .container
            .main-content
                block content
            .sidebar
                block sidebar
        footer
            block foot
```

Can anyone see what the problem may be? Maybe indenting?

Comment: `script(type='text/javascript').` - does this dot at the end of the line do anything? Might be easier for you to add your JS to an external file and just call it in like you do for `idle-timer.js`.

Comment: The dot apparantly is required because when I don't add it I get this warning in the console, "Implicit textOnly for `script` and `style` is deprecated.  Use `script.` or `style.` instead."

Comment: try checking the generated code in the source if you're getting the correct html. Also, you missed adding qoutations to `$('#info')`

Comment: Ah, yes I did thanks. Also, should the doc.ready() be placed in the external js file if I put the code there instead of in the head, or should that part be in the head and just the functions over in the external?

Comment: I was able to get an external javascript function to execute on a button click, but still nothing inside my document.ready is working.

Comment: So, what does the generated HTML look like?

Answer (score 1):

Hard to see on my mobile, but did you indent your script code like:

```
html
    head
        script(src='jsfile')
        script
            $(document).ready
    body #same level as head!
        header
```